# psycopg update doesn't work

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to use `psycopg` to update some rows in a postgres database and it doesn't do anything, the script runs without error but the database doesn't change.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=timetrack user=n")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select id, extract(epoch from begin_time) as b, extract(epoch from end_time) as e from activities;")
rows = cur.fetchall()

m = 10 ** 6
for i in range(0, len(rows)):
    row = rows[i]
    print(row)
    cur.execute("update activities set begin=(%s), \"end\"=(%s) where id=(%s);",
            (row[0] * m, row[1] * m, row[2]))

conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't do anything"? What's "it"? Which line is behaving differently than you expect? What did you expect? What actually happened?

Comment: Probably because you are using `epoch from end_time` as the `id` to `update`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I made a mistake in the indexing of the row variable. I wanted to set begin to begin, end to end, and id to id in the string. However, I ended up setting begin to id, end to begin, and id to begin. Postgres couldn't find any rows to update because the ids were wrong, so it did nothing.